# Special orthonormal basis for space of continuous real functions on a closed interval

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, continuity, hamel-basis, schauder-basis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. Let also $P = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ (with $n > 1$) be a finite subset of $[a,b]$ with all distinct elements ($x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n$). Let $C[a, b]$ be the real vector space of all continuous maps $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$. Of course $C[a, b]$ is also an inner product space with inner product $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx$.

Is there an orthonormal basis for the space $C[a, b]$ whose (infinitely many) elements $\{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfy the constraint that

(*) for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists one index $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $e_k(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$ for all $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ ?

Some polynomials exhibiting this property are the Lagrange polynomials $P_j(x) = \prod_{\substack{i=1 \\ i\neq j}}^{n} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$ (for $j = 1,\ldots, n$). However they are only finitely many so they cannot be a basis for the infinite-dimensional space $C[a,b]$.

The functions $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ belong to $C[a, b]$ and are linearly independent but not orthogonal. It should be possible to extend the set $\{P_1, \ldots, P_n\}$ to a base for $C[a, b]$ and then othonormalize it with Gram-Schmit. However extension and orthogonalization probably do not preserve the property (*).

**MOTIVATION:** When performing functional Principal Component Analysis in an infinite-dimensional function space one starts with a basis of the function space and finds a finite portion of that basis generating a finite-dimensional subspace with some desired properties. I would use a special basis with the property (*).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less difficult than you are making it. All you need to do is demarcate non-overlapping intervals $I_j$ about each of the $x_j$. Then for each $x_j$ define a function $e_j$ with the properties

- $e_j^{-1}((-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)) \subseteq I_j$
- $e_j(x_j) = 1$
- $\int_a^be_k^2(x)\,dx = 1$.

There are many ways to accomplish this. For example,

- For a given parameter $h$, define the function $g_h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by
  $$g_h(x) = \begin{cases}0& x\notin (-1,1)\\
  2h(x+1) & x\in(-1,-1/2]\\
  2(1-h)(x+1/2)+h & x \in(-1/2,0]\\
  2(h-1)x + 1 & x \in(0, 1/2]\\
  -2h(x-1/2) + h & x \in (1/2, 1)\end{cases}$$Note that $g_h(0) = 1$ and $g_h(\pm1/2) = h$.
- for each $1 \le j \le n$, select an $0 <\epsilon_j < \min \left\{\frac{x_j-x_{j-1}}2,\frac{x_{j+1}-x_j}2, 1\right\}$ (for $j=1,n$, dropping the term that is undefined). Set $I_j = (x_j -\epsilon_j, x_j+\epsilon_j) \cap [a,b]$.
- For given parameter $h_k$, define $$e_k(x) = g_{h_k}\left(\dfrac{x - x_k}{\epsilon_k}\right), x \in [a,b]$$Note that $e_k(x_k) = 1$.
- Choose each $h_k$ so that $\int_a^b e_k^2(x)\,dx = 1$. (Can you see why this will always be possible?)

Because the support (where they are non-zero) of the $e_k$ are each limited to the intervals $I_k$, which do not overlap, we have $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ as desired.

The set $\{e_k \mid 1\le k \le n\}$ spans a subspace $V$ of $C[a,b]$. Choose any orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}_{k > n}$ for $V^\perp$. Then the combined basis $\{e_k\}_{k =1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis for $C[a,b]$ having all the properties you wanted.